# howto run my backend api nodejs in background on startup on vps?

Tags: node.js, api, server, backend, webmin

i am struggling to get run my nodejs backend api on my Ubuntu vps.

the backend server is in a folder called /backend when i go in terminal and go into the folder i can start the process with

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.json --no-daemon
```

Than it runs..but when i close terminal than it closes.
I use webmin how can i handle that this will run in background and when reboot than autostart it?

i hope someone can help.
tried this addded systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=API

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/a
ExecStart=npm start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not had much experience with running Linux but have needed a similar thing in the past and used `nohup` for this - [Ubuntu Docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nohup.1.html)